# Image Rotation gives grayscale image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I got a problem with my Rotate image function in C++, Using OpenCV and Qt.
It kinda does his job, but not as expected, apart of being in grayscale, a part of the image seems to be duplicated at the top right.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

```
void ImgProcessing::rotate(cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat &tmp, int angle){

    float rads = angle*3.1415926/180.0;
    float cs = cos(-rads);
    float ss = sin(-rads);

    float xcenter = (float)(img.cols)/2.0;
    float ycenter = (float)(img.rows)/2.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++){

            int rorig = ycenter + ((float)(i)-ycenter)*cs - ((float)(j)-xcenter)*ss;
            int corig = xcenter + ((float)(i)-ycenter)*ss + ((float)(j)-xcenter)*cs;
            int pixel = 0;
            if (rorig >= 0 && rorig < img.rows && corig >= 0 && corig < img.cols) {
                     tmp.at<int>(i ,j) = img.at<int>(rorig, corig);
                  }else tmp.at<int>(i ,j) = 0;
        }

}
```

Can the problem be in accessing to the image pixels?

Comment: If you're using OpenCV, why not use [OpenCV's builtin functionality](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html) for this? It will be a lot more efficient. The `img.at<>` function is not efficient.

Comment: Know that aready, but that project will be reviewed by my professor, so I'm implementing all the linear&non-linear transformation by my self as we agreed on using opencv just for reading and saving the image matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you read in the image but I think you are accessing it incorrectly. It should be something like this:

```
Vec3b intensity = image.at<Vec3b>(j, i);
```

Comment: I thought the Vec3b was for accessing to the BGR channel Values.
And I'm reading the image normale with the imread opencv's function, and convert it to RGB then.

Comment: Just gave a try now, by accessing it via Vec3b is totally working!!!
Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great to hear that! As an explanation: Each location you access with (i,j) has three values R,G,B. So if you just use one int, you will just end up with one of those values.

Comment: Infact, for other transformations like Brightened, I access via Vec3b to (i, j) [k] for each rgb channel, and I was struggling figurining out how was possible to access to the entire vector keeping all channels in order to make kinda geometric distortions filters! Thanks again!